# Am I able to "return" two objects from a class for my route to send to my twig template?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, twig, slim

I'm new to the slim PHP micro framework and also to twig template system.

I'm wondering is there any way to "return" two objects from a PHP function so that my articles don't require two functions(e.g. getArticle,getComments)?

I know there is a way to do it with arrays but is there with objects like I am trying to do? See below.

Current class:

```
<?php
public function getArticle($id){
        $stmt = $this->app->engine->rows('SELECT null FROM articles WHERE id = :id', [':id' => $id]);

        if($stmt > 0){
            return $this->app->engine->testing('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = :id', [':id' => $id]);

        }else{
            return false;
        }
}
?>
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
<?php
public function getArticle($id){
        $stmt = $this->app->engine->rows('SELECT null FROM articles WHERE id = :id', [':id' => $id]);

        if($stmt > 0){
            $article = new stdClass();

            $article->main = $this->app->engine->testing('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = :id', [':id' => $id]);
            $article->comments = $this->app->engine->testing('SELECT * FROM articles_comments WHERE article_id = :id', [':id' => $id]);

            return 'both of the above to $article of route';

        }else{
            return false;
        }

}
?>
```

Route:

```
<?php
$app->get('/articles/:id', function ($id) use ($app) {
        $article = new stdClass();

        $article = $app->user->getArticle($id);
        $article->comments = $app->user->getComments($id);

        $app->render('article.html', ['article' => $article]);
});
?>
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
<?php
$app->get('/articles/:id', function ($id) use ($app) {
        $article = $app->user->getArticle($id);

        $article->main = 'use the returned $article->main';
        $article->comments = 'use the returned $article->comments';

        $app->render('article.html', ['article' => $article]);
});
?>
```

Twig template:

```
{{ article.main.title }}

{{ article.comments.message }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have 2 objects you have 1 object `$article` that has 2 properties.  Just `return $article;` and it will have `$article->main` and `$article->comments` properties:

```
$article = new stdClass();
$article->main = $this->app->engine->testing('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = :id', [':id' => $id]);
$article->comments = $this->app->engine->testing('SELECT * FROM articles_comments WHERE article_id = :id', [':id' => $id]);

return $article;
```

Then:

```
$article = $app->user->getArticle($id);

// print_r($article);
// $article->main and $article->comments are already part of $article

$app->render('article.html', ['article' => $article]);
```

Comment: This works when I print_r and dump the variable at route level, however at the level of the twig template only the .main variables seem to work.{% for c in article.comments %}
{{ c.something }}
{% endfor %}

the following twig syntax displays nothing